# vagrant undefined local variable or method in synce folders

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

my `vagrantfile` work perfectly but when i uncomment synce folder and set it to real path and make `vagrant reload` it return a exception:

```
/Users/pedrammarandi/pedram/Vagrantfile:41:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `“' for main:Object (NameError)
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:689:in `new'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:689:in `vagrantfile'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:441:in `host'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:207:in `block in action_runner'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:428:in `hook'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:671:in `unload'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

line 41:

```
   config.vm.synced_folder “/”, “/var/www/pedram.dev”
```

Answer (score 3):

you have something wrong with the funky character `“' and vagrant is telling your about it

```
undefined local variable or method `“'
```

maybe some copy/paste from ms word or something just put simple `"`

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/", "/var/www/pedram.dev"
```

it will run smoothly